# Contador reiniciar toda vez que zerar

Tags: javascript, contador

Tenho um contato de dia, hora, minuto e segundo, dai programo para exemplo: daqui 2 dias (regressivo), gostaria de quando ele zerar começasse a contar de novo, tipo de 2 em 2 dias, ou de 1 em um, para não precisar toda vez que zera ter que ficar fazendo alteração da data!
Segue o codigo:

```
var target_date = new Date("\n" + " October 15, 2019").getTime();
var dias, horas, minutos, segundos;
var regressiva = document.getElementById("regressiva");

setInterval(function() {

    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var segundos_f = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    dias = parseInt(segundos_f / 86400);
    segundos_f = segundos_f % 86400;

    horas = parseInt(segundos_f / 3600);
    segundos_f = segundos_f % 3600;

    minutos = parseInt(segundos_f / 60);
    segundos = parseInt(segundos_f % 60);


    document.getElementById('dia').innerHTML = dias;
    document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = horas;
    document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = minutos;
    document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = segundos;


}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Paulo, verifique se o timer chegou a zero e então atribua um novo valor ao target_date. Dessa forma sempre que o timer zerar será atribuído um novo timer de x dias a mais:

```
// (...)
var segundos_f = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
if (segundos_f <= 0) {
    const a = new Date();
    a.setDate(a.getDate() + 2 /* mais 2 dias, por exemplo */);
    target_date = a.getTime();
    return;
}
// (...)
```

Comment: então quando zera ele começa -1 -1 -1 -1 tipo assim, começa negativando e vai!

Comment: quanto atualizo a pagina ele volta do começo

Comment: @PauloJunior toda vez que a página é (re)carregada o script é interpretado novamente. Para salvar manter informações entre as trocas de páginas utilize algum mecanismo como o localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, session, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Olá Paulo eu fiz um exemplo, mas, não testei. Mas a lógica que implementei é bem simples:

**1.** Coloquei o dia na data em forma de [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) para ficar mais fácil de manipular os dias de contagem.

**2.** Retirei os códigos de dentro do **setInterval()** e inseri dentro de uma função, mais por uma questão de legibilidade.

**3.** Criei um **if** dentro da função para quando as horas, minutos e segundos forem zeros incrementar a data.

**4.** Também por legibilidade inseri `0` antes da hora, minutos e segundos menores que 10.

```js
var data = 15;
var target_date = new Date(`\n October ${data}, 2019`).getTime();
var dias, horas, minutos, segundos;
var regressiva = document.getElementById("regressiva");

setInterval(function() {
  Timer();
}, 1000);

function Timer() {
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var segundos_f = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  dias = parseInt(segundos_f / 86400);
  segundos_f = segundos_f % 86400;

  horas = parseInt(segundos_f / 3600);
  segundos_f = segundos_f % 3600;

  minutos = parseInt(segundos_f / 60);
  segundos = parseInt(segundos_f % 60);

  document.getElementById('dia').innerHTML = dias;
  document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = horas < 10 ? `0${horas}` : `${horas}`;
  document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = minutos < 10 ? `0${minutos}` : `${minutos}`;
  document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = segundos < 10 ? `0${segundos}` : `${segundos}`;
  
  if(horas == 0 && minutos == 0 && segundos == 0) {
    data = data + 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<b>Dias</b> <span id="dia"></span> -
<b>Tempo</b> <span id="hora"></span>:<span id="minuto"></span>:<span id="segundo"></span>
```

Comment: Cara ta faltando menos de 1 dia, ele fica bugado

Comment: Como vc está testando, fica bugado como?

Comment: tipo quando zera ele começa contagem progressiva e fica assim:  0:0-12:0-12:0-15

Comment: Então Paulo o problema é que está difícil de simular o problema, provavelmente essas contas de % e divisão por 1000 interferem no fluxo da contagem na função. Mas como não consegui testar, não saberei lhe dizer ao certo.

Comment: Então mas você teria um cronometro regressismo tipo esse, que faze-se dessa forma, zera ele acrescentasse 1 ou 2 dias!

Comment: Viu Paulo como está testando, pq aqui eu simulei e funcionou perfeitamente. Com o meu código eu coloquei 12 na variável data e setei o relógio do micro para 11:58, ao chegar em 00:00 ele adicionou 2 dias na variável dias e recomeçou a contagem regressiva normalmente.

Comment: Aqui não deu certo não, ele zerou dai chegou começou a contar negativo